# iOS connection does not return data

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

I've been making a web service for a simple iOS user system. PHP queries perfectly, but one issue - iOS isn't working out very well. Data isn't being received. How do I proceed? Here's my connection class:

```
import Foundation

class Connection: NSObject {
    var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    func login(username: String, password: String) {
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "localhost/getusers.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password)!
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var conn: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
    }

    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        println("didReceiveResponse")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData conData: NSData!) {
        self.data.appendData(conData)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        println(self.data)
    }

    deinit {
        println("deiniting")
    }
}
```

Here's where it's being called.

```
@IBAction func attemptLogin(sender: UIButton) {
        if(usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "") {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid Credentials", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            var connection: Connection = Connection()
            connection.login(usernameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text)
        }
    }
```

Lastly, here's the PHP service:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display errors', 1);

$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';

try {
    $DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=login_test', $username, $password);
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $recievedUsername = $_GET['username'];
    $recievedPassword = $_GET['password'];

    $data = array($recievedUsername, $recievedPassword);

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?");
    $STH->execute($data);

    $row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($row);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this in a compiled app? Your code works for me in that context.

Execution of a playground stops as soon as it gets to the end of your code, so there's nothing there for an asynchronous call to come back to. To make the playground keep running, import `XCPlayground` and add this line to the bottom:

```
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it in an app, but nothing is being outputted by the console.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the only thing I see would be that you didnt implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate to your class.... It should be

```
class Connection: NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate {...}
```

May it be possible that non of the delegate methods of NSURLConnection are currently called? Have you checked this?

Comment: `NSURLConnectionDelegate` is a rare duck-typed delegate - the parameter is just typed as `AnyObject`, so you don't necessarily need to *declare* conformance for your delegate method to be called (though it is good practice).

Comment: Tested it, they all run.